# How to use AWS Cognito with my own Login/MFA/Reset Password pages?

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to understand if/how I can use Cognito as an OCID / IdP but with my own "skin" to it.  Using the Cognito CSS customization is not nearly sufficient.

To be more precise, I am trying to build an SSO front-end that leverages Cognito's UserPools, Access/Refresh tokens, Device trusting/etc.  I have some specific requirements for i18n and additional authentication pages for MFA (would use the Cognito Custom Auth flows), but I cannot seem to understand how to tie these pieces together.

From what I can tell, if I use the Cognito SDK to build my SSO front end, then I am basically logging myself into my own SSO app, but then cannot use the generated credentials in an OCID flow.  And if I try to point my external applications to Cognito, then I am forced to use the hosted UI which does not meet my requirements at all.

How do I go about creating an SSO app that leverages Cognito?  Do I need to use Federated Identities somehow for this?  Or AWS STS (not even sure how that would come into play).  I looked at the idea of wrapping some of the Cognito calls via the API Gateway, but that leads me down a rabbit hole where I am basically rewriting a server to implement the OAuth2/OCID spec, which makes absolutely no sense.

Is there anyway to use Cognito to provide an single SSO experience across all my apps?  I do not need to support cross-domain apps, but do need the solution to support SPA, classic session-based server webapps and native mobile apps.

Comment: We had pretty much the same problem, ended up just using cognito basically as a user store and built our own SSO app on top using IdentityServer4. We issue id4 tokens and lose a bunch of out of the box functionality of cognito

Comment: @dpix In the end, we abandoned cognito and used Keycloak instead.  Building my own SSO app on top of it just didn't have the value for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have been able to gather, there is no way at present to create custom  Login/MFA/Reset Password pages when using the OIDC flow.  The only way is to use the supplied pages by Cognito which means no significant customization is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aws amplify lib for react https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/

Comment: I have but I don't see/understand how it helps me out.  From what I can tell from amplify is that it is a JS library to help me build the auth part into a js application, but it didn't help me pass  auth tokens to a web/mobile app if I am already logged in.  For instance, if I am logged in to a webapp on my phone, I want my mobile app to be logged in as well.  Similar to what Google or Facebook do.  I can't figure out how to make that work with cognito.

Comment: as per my knowledge, cognito does n't support what you are looking for. but you can raise a feature request in aws forum